# How to control the proportions of a QFrame in a layout?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt5, qframe

It's My Code. My Requirement:  if the Window Grows the frame also expands as per ratio in both directions.  I am trying with SetSize Policy, but nothing will happen. How to achieve it?

```
import sys
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class FrameExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame Example")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,600,600)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setFixedSize(200,200)
        # self.frame.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color:skyblue")

        self.frame1 = QFrame()
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QRect(10,10,600,600))
        self.frame1.resize(600,600)
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightgreen")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    countrywin =FrameExample()

    countrywin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please make yourself more clear. "expands as per ratio" -> what ratio? Also, as already told you, if you add widgets to a layout, setting their geometries (with any of `setGeometry`, `move` or `resize`) is completely pointless.

Comment: "expand as per ratio: " - Want to increase the frame size (width-wise as well as height wise) based on main window size @musicamante

Comment: It's clear that you intend a growth based on the main window, but, again, *what ratio*? A ratio means a proportion, so, since there's no trace of that in your code, nor in your question, it's really unclear what you want to achieve. Please add more details, find a way to better explain what you want to achieve and eventually provide an image/animation of what you need.

Comment: in my code, the first frame is fixed size, I want to change that frame based on widow size ( at the beginning(window size: 600X600), my frame requirement is 200x200,  but if we change the window size,  the frame also changed,proportionate.@musicamante

Comment: Are you looking for [`setMinimumSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMinimumSize-1) and [`setMaximumSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMaximumSize-1)?

Comment: if we setMinimumize and SetMaxmimumSize to the first frame, the second frame also affected.  My requirement., My first frame is the fixed size at the beginning of the program, if we expand the window, the first frame also expands,@Art

Comment: @Bala should it expand both height and width? or only expand the width?

Comment: Only wiidth @art

Comment: @Bala ok, for future reference try to be more clear in the question first, as you didn't specify the *proportion* of the frame (a third, but *you* should tell that to us, it's not our job to *imagine* that), and since you also set a fixed size, it all became even more confusing. Always try to put yourself in our shoes: imagine we don't know *anything* about what you want to achieve, and you have to explain everything in order to let us understand that since the beginning, so that we (which includes *you*) can avoid unnecessary comments, confusion and delayed answers.

Comment: sorry, Try our level best in future. Thankyou @musicamante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it appears you want the top frame to get a third of the width (i.e. `200/600 == 1/3`), with the height remaining fixed - but it should not resize smaller than the minimum in either direction. Meanwhile, the bottom frame should just take up whatever space is left over.

This can be achieved by firstly setting the [minimum-size](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) and an appropriate [size-policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) on the top frame. Its proportions can then be controlled by putting it in a horizontal layout and [adding stretchers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) with appropriate stretch factors (depending on how the frame should be aligned).

Here is a working example based on your code:

```
import sys
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class FrameExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color:skyblue")

        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        # align left
        hbox.addWidget(self.frame, 1)
        hbox.addStretch(2)

        # align centre
        # hbox.addStretch()
        # hbox.addWidget(self.frame)
        # hbox.addStretch()

        self.frame1 = QFrame()
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background-color:lightgreen")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(hbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame1)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    countrywin =FrameExample()

    countrywin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thats what, I Need -------Thankyou @ ekhumoro

Comment: How to add a Qwidget in the first frame ( for example add Qpushbutton in the top frame). try so many things, I got either frame size changed or nothing will add to the frame.

Comment: @Bala You need to set a layout on the frame and then add child widgets to the layout.